# perl/awk/sed one liner for removing directory name from a text file containing list of paths

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I've a text file of the following format:

```
/path1/path2/file.ext:20 ..................
/path1/path2/file2.ext:120 ..................
/path4/file.ext:93 ..................
```

I would like to get the output in the following format:

```
file.ext:20 ..................
file2.ext:120 ..................
file.ext:93 ..................
```

using perl/awk/sed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple sed would do:

```
sed 's|^.*/||g' file
```

Awk:

```
awk 'sub(/^.*\//, "")' file
```

Or

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file
```

Comment: As long as there are no more `/`s later in the line (Yeah, I'm being that guy).  +1.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With perl,

```
perl -pe 's|.*/||' file
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution in perl:

One using File::Basename:

```
perl -MFile::Basename -ne 'print basename $_' FILE
```

Comment: `/gio` does not seem useful

Comment: true, doesnt come into effect with the sbstitution. ->removed

Answer (score 2):

With grep

```
grep -oP '.*/\K.*' file
```

Comment: I don't think you need the leading `.*`.

Comment: @tripleee without it it removes only the first `/`